# Why can't I identify the elements on the history page in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

The first element in the chrome history is a checkbox whose id is checkbox-0

But I can't see it from the console.  I can't see any checkboxes from the console.

[image]

and see this pic

[image]

The elements are showing on the elements tab of the developer tools. But not showing in the console.

Why is that, and how can I set - enable / disable those checkboxes from the console.  I know how to normally but I can't seem to get a reference to any checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can goto `chrome://history-frame` and run

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]'), function(el) { el.checked = true });
```

to check all of the checkboxes. You need to ensure you are running your js on the correct document.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple frames on the page and the console only works with one at a time. You can switch frames with the drop just above the console (see screenshot).

[image: Selecting the Frame]

Answer (score 0):

rlemon got there first and his tip to go to chrome://history-frame  got the item detected.  I like luggage's drop down solution a lot too.

As for the javascript, I used this

two lines of javascript

```
assa=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i=0;i<assa.length;i++) assa[i].checked=true
```

That checks all the boxes.

Then I saw the remove button wasn't enabled.. I manually clicked and unclicked the first checkbox which enabled the remove button.

Then of course clicked the remove button and problem solved. All items listed in that history search, are removed.